# Yeoman grunt copying whole bower_component folder for distribution

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

When using Yeoman with the angular generator, I build a dist by running grunt. This works great but my question is that why does the dist folder also contain all the bower components when I actually just need the min.js ones.

Is there a setting in the grunt file I can hack to get only the min.js files in a vendor folder, to keep the dist. as small as possible?

I am currently manually creating a vendor folder and copying the min.js files to it referencing them in my index.html, but it would be great if I could automate that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is way Yeoman create the project and the grunt file. So you can customize the grunt.js file in order to omit the unwanted files.

In the `grunt.js` file replace the `'bower_components/**/*',` to `'bower_components/**/*.min.js',`

This will copy only the `min.js` files.

Hope this will help.

Comment: What about resources referenced without the min.js? like; `bower_components/angular-underscore/angular-underscore.js`